# CSS Forcing Object To Be A Certain Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that has many profiles using bootstrap. The profile was taken from here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/profile-card.

Problem is that some people's information takes up one more line than the others which cause the profiles not to be even. How do I force them all to be the same size (In this case most of them would be one line longer than they otherwise would, in order to accommodate the few that have more information)?

So for example in the example there the code is this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">

      <div class="card hovercard">
        <div class="cardheader">

        </div>
        <div class="avatar">
          <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="title">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://scripteden.com/">Script Eden</a>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">Passionate designer</div>
          <div class="desc">Curious developer</div>
          <div class="desc">Tech geek</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-twitter btn-sm" href="https://twitter.com/webmaniac">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" rel="publisher"
             href="https://plus.google.com/+ahmshahnuralam">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" rel="publisher"
             href="https://plus.google.com/shahnuralam">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's say you want to accommodate that on someone's profile instead of just saying, Passionate designer, it would say something that takes up two lines, that would then make their entire profile box 1 line longer which would in turn mess up the entire page. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to share your code. Please give us a [mcve] of what's happening now.

Comment: Please see what I added

Comment: That doesn't replicate the issue. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bWrMmY

Comment: Why don't you the height of your div containing the info. and set CSS as overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; whitespace: no-wrap;